# basic xml setting value javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Hi this seems to be a basic question but I can't get it right.
I have an xml which looks like this:

```
<xml id="emailBodyXML"><email><body></body></email></xml>
```

Now I have a variable, 'emailBody' that contains text values.
I want to be able to put the value of the emailBody inside the body tag. For example emaiLBody="Hello". I want my xml to look like this:

```
<email><body>Hello</body></email>
```

so how do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var emailBody = 'Hello';

var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

bodyTag[0].innerHTML = emailBody;
```